# How to determine what week a day belongs to

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm having trouble categorizing which week of the month a day belongs to. So, I'm counting a week as first Sunday that passed, even if that week has one or two days, it will be counted as a week. I've attached a photo in order to be more clear in my explanation:

[image]

Until now, I have used:

```
Week 1: 
=IF(AND(DAY(A2)>=1;DAY(A2)<=7);(TIME(HOUR(B2);MINUTE(B2);0)-TIME(HOUR(A2);MINUTE(A2);0))*24;0)

Week 2:
=IF(AND(DAY(A2)>=8;DAY(A2)<=14);(TIME(HOUR(B2);MINUTE(B2);0)-TIME(HOUR(A2);MINUTE(A2);0))*24;0)

Week 3:
=IF(AND(DAY(A2)>=15;DAY(A2)<=21);(TIME(HOUR(B2);MINUTE(B2);0)-TIME(HOUR(A2);MINUTE(A2);0))*24;0)

Week 4:
=IF(AND(DAY(A2)>=22;DAY(A2)<=28);(TIME(HOUR(B2);MINUTE(B2);0)-TIME(HOUR(A2);MINUTE(A2);0))*24;0)

And also Week 5 if the month exceeds 28 days or so:
=IF(DAY(A2)>28;(TIME(HOUR(B2);MINUTE(B2);0)-TIME(HOUR(A2);MINUTE(A2);0))*24;0)
```

For example in May:

Week 1: May 1-5 not May 1-7, because the 6th and 7th day of May would be Week 2, according to my wrong formula...
Week 2: May 6-12
Week 3: May 13-19
Week 4: May 20-26
Week 5: May 27-31

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, to get week of month you can use:

```
=WEEKNUM(A1,2)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),2)+1
```

The `2` in `WEEKNUM()` refers to `Monday` as first day of the week, but you can change that.

Comment: Oh, that works like magic, one more question, how would my IFs gonna change, cause this formula now retrieve me the no of the week and I want to categorize my days in week columns: Week 1, Week 2 and so on. Thank you very much for the answer!!

Comment: @Flaw98 Well, if you can post the desired output as a table I can help you with that as well :)

Comment: So, I have some activities: https://imgur.com/a/5feupo0, whom duration has to be calculated and then assigned to the right week of the month, like this https://imgur.com/UTYkPS5. In the past, I have used the IFs and assigned it to the right category using the rule 1-7, 8-14, 15-21 and so on. Hope I made myself clear in the explanation and also, thanks again!!

Comment: Just change the `AND()` part of if into `(above function)` = `respective week number`

Comment: So, the final formula will be `=IF(WEEKNUM(A4;2)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A4);MONTH(A4);1);2)+1=3;(TIME(HOUR(B4);MINUTE(B4);0)-TIME(HOUR(A4);MINUTE(A4);0))*24;0)`, maybe it will be useful to someone else too.